# Why ES6 (7/8...) is able to be compatible with ES5(3) since there is so much difference in grammar?

Tags: python-3.x, ecmascript-6

Addition: Why Python3 choose to design new features at cost of compatibility? Is there anything to do with the nature of language?

Comment: I've posted an answer to the title of your question, which can be objectively answered. The *body* of your question calls for opinions, which is off-topic for SO. Please edit the question body so that it doesn't call for opinions (or delete the question -- if you want to do that and my answer has a positive score, just ping me and I'll delete the answer so it doesn't get in your way when deleting the question).

Answer (score 2):

> Why ES6 (7/8…) is able to be compatible with ES5(3) since there is so much difference in grammar?

There aren't *differences* so much as *additions*. When new grammar/syntax is added in JavaScript, it's defined carefully so that it would have been a syntax error in earlier versions. That's important, because maintaining backward compatibility with the **mind-bogglingly huge** amount of JavaScript code out in the wild is an important goal for the committee that moves JavaScript forward (ECMA's TC39). (Backward compatibility isn't 100%, but it's about 99.9999%.) But if something new would have been a syntax error before, then there isn't any working code out there that has the new thing.

For example: Adding `async` functions. In JavaScript from the beginning, a function declaration looks like this:

```
function example() {
    // ...
}
```

To create `async` functions, it became possible to put `async` in front of `function`:

```
async function example() {
    // ...
}
```

That's new grammar. It only works because before it was added, that would have been a syntax error, the same one you get if you do this today:

```
blah function example() {]
    // ...
}
```

Similarly, with parameter default values, you specify the default value with an `=` and an expression in the parameter list:

```
function example(param = "default") {
    // ...
}
```

That was a syntax error until it was added. So were arrow functions, generator functions, `class` syntax, nullish coalescing, optional chaining, destructuring, and other new grammar/syntax.

So since these would have been syntax errors, they don't exist in working code out in the wild.